# Kibana displays "Searching...", displays no results. Confirmed data exists in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to build a new index, but I have run into some issues in Kibana. The Discover page has displayed "Searching..." for several hours now, on just a handful of data points. I think there may be an issue with the formatting?

The indices page shows that Average, Maximum, and Minimum are all numbers, analyzed= false, indexed= true .
InstanceID, MetricName,Region are all string, analyzed and indexed = True.
Timestamp is a date

Does any of this indicate what the issue may be?

**Edit:**
Additional Info from Warning: "Doc values are not enabled on this field. This may lead to excess heap consumption when visualizing" ...AND... 
"This is an analyzed string field. Analyzed strings are highly unique and can use a lot of memory to analyze"

**Edit 2:**
A few notes:
My mappings do not seem to be working properly.

```
Invoke-RestMethod "$URI/mytestindex/t2credbal" -Method post -body '{
  "mytestindex": {
   "mappings": {
     "t2credbal": { 
       "properties": {
        "timestamp": {"type":"date"},
        "minimum": {"type":"number", "index":"no", "fielddata": { "format": "doc_values" } },
        "maximum": {"type":"number", "index":"no", "fielddata": { "format": "doc_values" } },
        "average": {"type":"number", "index":"no", "fielddata": { "format": "doc_values" } }   
          }  } } } }'
```

When I run the command above, my fields show up as mytestindex.mappings.t2credbal.properties.timestamp, instead of just timestamp

My values are reporting in as Records.Timestamp (per the command below), with the proper field type, so I do not feel that specifying the mappings are totally necessary in my case. However, Kibana is not able to search and analyze the data, although it is listed in ElasticSearch exactly as I anticipated.

```
$json= {Records:  [
   {
    "Minimum":  280.91,
    "Maximum":  280.97,
    "Average":  280.94416666666672,
    "Timestamp":  "2015-04-27T13:12:00Z",
    "InstanceID":  "i-65e2b951",
    "MetricName":  "CPUCreditBalance",
    "Region":  "eu-west-1"
   }

Invoke-RestMethod "$URI/mytestindex/t2credbal/" -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'
```

**EDIT #3**

I adjusted the timestamp format to one that has worked for me in my other index; however I am getting the following errors upon trying to visualize the timestamp field:

```
Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[S73SynuOQzW4NKbwPN7tTg][mytestindex][0]: SearchParseException[[mytestindex][0]: 
query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"Records.Timestamp\",\"interval\":\"0ms\",\"pre_zone\":\"-04:00\",\"pre_zone_adjust_large_interval\":true,\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{\"min\":1430158024806,\"max\":1430158924806}}}}}]]]; nested: 
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Zero or negative time interval not supported]; }{[S73SynuOQzW4NKbwPN7tTg][mytestindex][1]: SearchParseException[[mytestindex][1]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"Records.Timestamp\",\"interval\":\"0ms\",\"pre_zone\":\"-04:00\",\"pre_zone_adjust_large_interval\":true,\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{\"min\":1430158024806,\"max\":1430158924806}}}}}]]]; nested:
 ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Zero or negative time interval not supported]; }{[S73SynuOQzW4NKbwPN7tTg][mytestindex][2]: SearchParseException[[mytestindex][2]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"Records.Timestamp\",\"interval\":\"0ms\",\"pre_zone\":\"-04:00\",\"pre_zone_adjust_large_interval\":true,\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{\"min\":1430158024806,\"max\":1430158924806}}}}}]]]; nested: 
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Zero or negative time interval not supported]; }{[S73SynuOQzW4NKbwPN7tTg][mytestindex][3]: SearchParseException[[mytestindex][3]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"Records.Timestamp\",\"interval\":\"0ms\",\"pre_zone\":\"-04:00\",\"pre_zone_adjust_large_interval\":true,\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{\"min\":1430158024806,\"max\":1430158924806}}}}}]]]; nested: 
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Zero or negative time interval not supported]; }{[S73SynuOQzW4NKbwPN7tTg][mytestindex][4]: SearchParseException[[mytestindex][4]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"Records.Timestamp\",\"interval\":\"0ms\",\"pre_zone\":\"-04:00\",\"pre_zone_adjust_large_interval\":true,\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{\"min\":1430158024806,\"max\":1430158924806}}}}}]]]; nested: 
 ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Zero or negative time interval not supported]; }]"}
at http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:42978:38
at Function.Promise.try (http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:46205:26)
at http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:46183:27
at Array.map (native)
at Function.Promise.map (http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:46182:30)
at callResponseHandlers (http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:42950:22)
at http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:43068:16
at wrappedCallback (http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:20873:81)
at wrappedCallback (http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:20873:81)
at http://myurl.com/index.js?_b=5930:20959:26
```

**Edit #4**

Fixed the timestamp format.
Verified that the results are displayed as expected using the _search? syntax.
Completely blew out and recreated my index, verified that all field names and types are correct.
The Discover screen now displays "no results" instead of "Searching...". 
When I change the time interval from 15 minutes to any other value, I get the following:

```
Discover: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Notifier.error (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:45607:23)
at Notifier.bound (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:32081:21)
at myurl/index.js?_b=5930:118772:18
at wrappedCallback (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:20873:81)
at myurl/index.js?_b=5930:20959:26
at Scope.$eval (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:22002:28)
at Scope.$digest (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:21814:31)
at Scope.$apply (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:22106:24)
at done (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:17641:45)
at completeRequest (myurl/index.js?_b=5930:17855:7)
```

Comment: Did you specify which analyzer to use ? if so, which one ? can you find the fields you want by accessing `_search?` (doing a lite search)

Comment: I did not specify one... I'm pretty new to ES, so I don't know much about them yet.

The sample datapoint I posted above is from a _search result

Comment: This is not enough information. If you want, you can update your post with full details: index mapping and a few curl commands to insert data. This way it can be reproducible. Further, which versions of elasticsearch and kibana are you using?

Comment: More edits made. Specifying mappings do not seem to be necessary, as ElasticSeach is properly analyzing the fields and listing them as the correct type in Kibana (string, number). Attempting to specify them seems to just create more issues.

Comment: Also, I think the Timestamp field may be the source of the issue. Kibana shows 0 results when I attempt to visualize that field... I will try playing with the formatting on that.

Comment: Unless it's code you posted, `"Timestamp":  "\/Date(1430066400000)\/",` is not a valid timestamp. If you refuse to post the mapping of this index - it'll not be easy to help you.

Comment: I converted the timestamp to the  "Timestamp":  "2015-04-27T12:20:00" format, but I am getting date internal errors now. See OP for full message.

Comment: Elasticsearch field-names are case sensitive, Your mapping shows `timestamp ` while you try to index: `Timestamp`. I'm not sure if that's the core of the issue - but it's definitely worth testing. BTW - same goes to the rest of the fields, i.e. `minimum` vs. `Minimum` and etc.

Comment: @alfasin thanks for all of your suggestions so far. The issue I am running into now seems to be a Kibana related bug. 

Shards: 5 Successful: 5 Failed: 0

Comment: "Shards: 5 Successful: 5 Failed: 0" - related to which request?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making sense... 

After fixing the date format issues I was having, I used the /_search? API in ElasticSearch to pull my records. They all looked correct, and I confirmed that all 5 shards were successful, no failures.

Kibana no longer shows "Searching...", it just says 0 results when I go to Discover, but then I get the error message above (in the OP) when I change the time picker to another interval besides Last 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by correcting the date format in ElasticSearch. The Powershell convertto-json command in my script was converting a timestamp object to a date format that did not cooperate with Kibana. After setting the date format to yyyy-MM-hhThh:mm:ss , the issue of never-ending "Searching..." went away, but new problems arose.

Will be posting that issue separately.

Comment: To follow up, I have completely resolved the issues. Kibana did not like me entering the stats as sub-types of "Records", so I adjusted my script to POST my JSON objects individually, using a foreach statement.

By entering the data in the format:

{
    "Minimum":  279.29,
    "Maximum":  279.43,
    "Average":  279.35833333333335,
    "Timestamp":  "2015-04-30T08:17:00Z",
    "InstanceID":  "i-d0be991a",
    "MetricName":  "CPUCreditBalance",
    "Region":  "ap-southeast-1"
}

, I was able to display the data as intended.

Comment: I have the same problem but the solution above did not work.